# Node.js with mongoose delete one array element

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to delete one array element when I click delete button on jade view page.

When clicked, it's going to send selected instructor objected as req.body.

At sever side, it will find courses that contain the instructor objectId.

Any idea for me?

Thank you for reading it.

here is my code:

```
var id = req.body._id;
clist.find({ instructors: { $in: [id] } }).exec(function (err, result) {
            result.forEach(function (obj) {
                clist.update(
                    { _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(obj._id)},
                    { $pull: { instructors : [new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)] } }
                );
                console.log(new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(obj._id) + ' was deleted');
            });
        });
```

Schema Clist and ilist:

```
var instructorlist = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: Number, required: true },
    gender: { type: String, required: true },
    DOB: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    phone: { type: Number, required: true },
    address: { type: String, required: true },
    dateofstart: { type: Date, required: true},
    courses: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "clist"
    }]
});
var courselist = mongoose.Schema({
    coursename: { type: String, required: true },
    coursenumber: { type: String, required: true },
    coursecredit: { type: Number, required: true },
    courseroom: { type: String, required: false },
    courseregisteddate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    students: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "slist"
    }],
    instructors: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "ilist"
    }]
});
```

one example for mongodb :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "591a7a3b391a1842e8a69e23"
    },
    "coursename": "JDKD",
    "coursenumber": "COMP4483",
    "coursecredit": 4,
    "courseroom": "sdaf",
    "instructors": [
        {
            "$oid": "591a374422a3a13d38c0bbe5"
        }
    ],
    "students": [],
    "courseregisteddate": {
        "$date": "2017-05-16T04:04:11.848Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

When I add instructor objectID in Course.

```
var newcourse = new clist({
                    'coursename': req.body.coursename, 'coursenumber': req.body.coursenumber, 'coursecredit': req.body.coursecredit
                    , 'courseroom': req.body.room, 'instructors': instructors._id
                });
```

Comment: Can you post the schema for whatever becomes the 'clist' model?

Comment: @Paul I updated my posting.

Comment: Why you using loop there ?

Comment: @Love-Kesh because one instructor would have more than one course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use same operation to find and update multiple**

```
clist.update(
  { instructors: { $in: [id] }},
  { $pull: { instructors : { _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } } }, //or{ $pull: { instructors: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } }
  {
   multi:true
 },
 function(error, success){
  if(error){
   console.log("error",error)

 }
 console.log("success",success)

});
```

Comment: success { ok: 1,
  nModified: 0,
  n: 2,
  opTime:
   { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 3, high_: 1494912734 },
     t: 1 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001 }

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it!

Comment: if try  { $pull: { instructors : { _id : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } } } then  { $pull: { instructors : { $oid : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } } }

Comment: Try this  { $pull: { instructors : { _id : id } } }

Comment: tried { $pull: { instructors : { _id : id } } }, { $pull: { instructors : id  } }, { $pull: { instructors : mongoose.Types.Objectid( id) } } } but same result like success something.

Comment: { $pull: { instructors:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)  } } worked.. thank you !!

Comment: welcome @ChiSeongOh , i came with another try   { $pull: { instructors : { '$oid' : new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) } } } , make string '$oid'